# How to extract an attribute's value from JSON object when another attribute's value from same object is known

Tags: json, jq

In a bash shell script, I want to extract `Arn`, `DefaultVersionId` from following JSON where `Arn` string contains word *akshay*:

```json
[
    {
            "PolicyName": "my-buckets-all",
            "PolicyId": "ABCDEF",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::12345:policy/my-buckets-all",
            "Path": "/",
            "DefaultVersionId": "v1",
            "AttachmentCount": 0,
            "PermissionsBoundaryUsageCount": 0,
            "IsAttachable": true,
            "CreateDate": "2022-05-14T01:17:13+00:00",
            "UpdateDate": "2022-05-14T01:17:13+00:00"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "akshay-buckets-all",
            "PolicyId": "GHIJK",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::12345:policy/akshay-buckets-all",
            "Path": "/",
            "DefaultVersionId": "v4",
            "AttachmentCount": 1,
            "PermissionsBoundaryUsageCount": 0,
            "IsAttachable": true,
            "CreateDate": "2022-05-20T21:20:10+00:00",
            "UpdateDate": "2022-07-28T19:15:09+00:00"
        }
]
```

I am fiddling with `jq` to get this done. When tried with following, I just get the `Arn` and not `DefaultVersionId`:

```
.[] | .Arn, .DefaultVersionId | select(contains("akshay"))
```

How to go about it?

`jqplay` fiddle here: https://jqplay.org/s/gp1DYAG-rgU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the required objects first (based on your condition) and then extract the fields needed, i.e.

```
map( select( .Arn | contains( "akshay" ) )? )[] | .Arn, .DefaultVersionId
```

gets you the values on a multi-line output. To get the values on the same line separated by a single whitespace use `"\(.Arn) \(.DefaultVersionId)"` after the pipe symbol.

Note that `contains` looks for an exact match of the search string and does *not* satisfy case insensitivity. To do so use `test("akshay"; "i")` instead.

`jqplay` link - https://jqplay.org/s/JzzfzqYWXYN